# Installing KAA (python console editor) on Windows

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install Kaa editor on Windows (it runs great on Linux).

https://github.com/kaaedit/kaa

It depends on Curses_ex, which must be compiled in Windows.

- But I don't have a Visual Studio,
- The only curses precompiled I found on the web is for Python 3.2 - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Kaa requires Python 3.3+  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Is there a solution to install kaa (or compile curses) without installing VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an author of kaa.

I haven't try kaa in Windows yet, but I'm afraid kaa doesn't work in Windows out of box. PDCurses lacks some functionaries used by kaa(e.g, key_defined()), and console window doesn't support unicode character.

I expect we can run kaa in Cygwin version of Python on mintty, but Cygwin doesn't ship Python 3.3 yet.

I'll look into these issues later. So, for the meantime, please play kaa on Ubuntu or Mac.